# First position occurrences in a list of lists

Tags: haskell

So i have for example this list `[[2,1,3],[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2]]`. What I want from it is to get a list which tells me how many times each of the numbers (in this example just 3) comes in the first position.

```
length $ filter (\a -> head a == ???) ([[2,1,3],[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2]])
```

The `???` should be 1-2-3, so my result will be [1,2,1] - 1 list has 1 in first position, 2 have the 2 as first position and 1 has 3 as first position.

I am a new to Haskell and I am trying to figure out the proper definition!

Comment: `map length . group . sort . map head`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to solve this at once. Start by just creating a list of list beginnings.
So that you get:

```
[2,1,2,3]
```

You can then sort, group and count later.